How to find the value between IP and IP using Ansible?
I would like to find the value between IP and IP using Ansible.
For example, I want to find IP address that between 192.168.0.25 and 192.168.0.30. The expected results are as follow
{
  "results": [
    "192.168.0.25",
    "192.168.0.26",
    "192.168.0.27",
    "192.168.0.28",
    "192.168.0.29"
  ]
}

How can we derive the result value as above?
I tried to find a way to use the ipaddr filter, but I couldn't find it.
Thanks.

Sound more like one would need to Develop a Custom Filter or Module based on something like Python 3: Create a list of possible IP addresses. There might already one exist usable_range filter – Expand the usable IP addresses ...

Get the indexes
  ip_start: 192.168.0.25
  ip_stop: 192.168.0.30
  index_start: "{{ ip_start | split('.') | last }}"
  index_stop: "{{ ip_stop | split('.') | last }}"

Declare the subnet and create the list of IPs
  subnet: "{{ (ip_start ~ '/24') | ansible.utils.ipsubnet }}"
  ip_range: "{{ subnet | ansible.utils.usable_range }}"

Get the slice
  results: "{{ ip_range.usable_ips[index_start|int:index_stop|int] }}"

gives
  results:
  - 192.168.0.25
  - 192.168.0.26
  - 192.168.0.27
  - 192.168.0.28
  - 192.168.0.29



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    ip_start: 192.168.0.25
    ip_stop: 192.168.0.30
    index_start: "{{ ip_start | split('.') | last }}"
    index_stop: "{{ ip_stop | split('.') | last }}"

    subnet: "{{ (ip_start ~ '/24') | ansible.utils.ipsubnet }}"
    ip_range: "{{ subnet | ansible.utils.usable_range }}"
    results: "{{ ip_range.usable_ips[index_start|int:index_stop|int] }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: subnet

    - debug:
        var: ip_range

    - debug:
        var: results

Optionally, get the indexes from the list of IPs
    index_start: "{{ ip_range.usable_ips.index(ip_start) }}"
    index_stop: "{{ ip_range.usable_ips.index(ip_stop) }}"


